# Cross browser "jump to"/"scroll" textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a textarea with many lines of input, and a JavaScript event fires that necessitates I scroll the textarea to line 345.

`scrollTop` sort of does what I want, except as far as I can tell it's pixel level, and I want something that operates on a line level. What also complicates things is that, afaik once again, it's not possible to make textareas not line-wrap.

Comment: Could you give a bit more background on what you are trying to do. In particular, does it definatly have to be a textarea? ie. will users be editing its contents?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can stop wrapping with the wrap attribute. It is not part of HTML 4, but most browsers support it.
You can compute the height of a line by dividing the height of the area by its number of rows.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function Jump(line)
{
  var ta = document.getElementById("TextArea");
  var lineHeight = ta.clientHeight / ta.rows;
  var jump = (line - 1) * lineHeight;
  ta.scrollTop = jump;
}
</script>

<textarea name="TextArea" id="TextArea" 
  rows="40" cols="80" title="Paste text here"
  wrap="off"></textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="Jump(98)" title="Go!" value="Jump"/>
```

Tested OK in FF3 and IE6.

Answer (score 3):

If you use .scrollHeight instead of .clientHeight, it will work properly for textareas that are shown with a limited height and a scrollbar:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function Jump(line)
{
  var ta = document.getElementById("TextArea");
  var lineHeight = ta.scrollHeight / ta.rows;
  var jump = (line - 1) * lineHeight;
  ta.scrollTop = jump;
}
</script>

<textarea name="TextArea" id="TextArea" 
  rows="40" cols="80" title="Paste text here"
  wrap="off"></textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="Jump(98)" title="Go!" value="Jump"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something to consider when referring to the accepted answer: you may not have specified the `rows` attribute in your `textarea` e.g. instead, you may have set the height of the `textarea` using CSS.

Therefore referring to `ta.rows` will not work as per above (it's 2 by default), so instead you could get the `line-height` of your `textarea` via `currentStyle` / `getComputedStyle` or even jQuery's `.css()`, and do something like the following:

```js
function jump(line) {
  var ta = document.getElementById("TextArea");
  var jump = line * parseInt(getStyle(ta, 'line-height'), 10);
  ta.scrollTop = jump;
}

function getStyle(el, styleProp) {
  if (el.currentStyle) {
    var y = el.currentStyle[styleProp];
  } else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
    var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
  }
  return y;
}
```